# Having issue when trying to print out the value I need

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
import sys

Even_Sum = 0
Odd_Sum = 0
Difference_Sum = 0
TotalEven = 0
TotalOdd = 0
CenteredAverage = 0
Sum = 0
max_value = 0
min_value = 0

len(sys.argv)
num = int(sys.argv[1])
if ValueError:
    print("Please enter valid integers!")
else:
    for i in range(num):
        if num[i]%2 == 0:
            Even_Sum = Even_Sum + num[i]
        else:
            Odd_Sum = Odd_Sum + num[i]
    Difference_Sum = max.num - min.num
    for num in int(sys.argv[1]):
        if num% 2 == 0:
            TotalEven += 1
        else:
            TotalOdd += 1
    for x in num:
        max_value = max(max_value, x)
        min_value = min(min_value, x)
        sum += x
        CenteredAverage = (sum - max_value - min_value) / (len(num) - 2)
    print("The sum of all numbers is " +
          Even_Sum +
          ", the sum of all odd numbers is " +
          Odd_Sum +
          ", the difference between the biggest and smallest number is " +
          Difference_Sum +
          ", the total number of even numbers is " +
          TotalEven +
          ", the total number of odd numbers is " +
          TotalOdd +
          ", the centered averaged is " +
          CenteredAverage + ".")
```

Input:

```
python EvenOddCalculator.py 12,2,8,7,100
```

Expected Output:

```
The sum of all even numbers is 122, the sum of all odd numbers is 7,
the difference between the biggest and smallest number is 98, the
total number of even numbers is 4, the total number of odd numbers is
1, the centered average is 9.
```

I have inputted the correct formula and also integer input but when I try to run the program it doesn't work and I will just be getting an error. Need some advice regarding this issue

Comment: And the error is...? Please [edit] your question and be specific.

Comment: code runs for me, what is the error?